# I'm using lookups in Azure Data Factory to update only new data but I'm getting errors and I can't see why

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure Data Factory to copy data from one Azure database to another Azure database, but I only want to copy across the new data. So I'm using lookups to achieve this. LookupOld is the destination database that needs to be updated, LookupNew is the Source database. Both tables have identical columns. The unique identifier is reportline_id, LookupOld has reportline_id 1 to 80 and lookupNew has reportline_id 1 to 157, so I need to copy across reportline_id 81 to 157 from my source to the destination.

I'm using the following query to copy the data:
Select * from dbo.report_line where reportline_id > '@{activity('lookupOld').output.reportline_id}'

[image]

But when I run the debug I get the following error, and I can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

I've previewed the data for all the stages and everything looks fine.
This is my first day using ADF and I'd be very grateful for some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the output of the Lookup activity.

[image: Source: mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6185/azure-data-factory-lookup-activity-example/]

The JSON output is different from your expression, you are probably missing **value**. So it should look something like this:

```
@concat('Select * from dbo.report_line where reportline_id > ', activity('lookupOld').output.value.reportline_id)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I realised I hadn't named the column reportline_id as I had a Max calculation on it. I've updated that and also amended the expression to include value, but I'm now getting another error.  "The expression 'activity('LookupOld').output.value.reportline_id' cannot be evaluated because property 'reportline_id' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an integer index."

Comment: Yeah, that is because multiple elements (could be/are) returned and your expression only excepts only one record. You could select the option firstRow or select the first value return by the query using activity('LookupOld').output.value.reportline_id[0]. The [0] selects the first value of the array, arrays start with the value zero.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for this!  This was the only place on the Internet where I could find this addressed, and frankly it's a pretty basic piece of functionality that should be part of a tutorial.

I've boiled it a little for my use -- your two steps are spot-on, a Lookup then a Copy.  The Lookup --

```
    select CONVERT(varchar, max(time_queued), 21) max_time_queued from FastQ_Branch_Appointment_Time_At_Time_Customer_Queued
```

That captures the most recent record's timestamp, as a string, from the destination table where **time_queued** is the datetime we're using to make the decision.  It puts it into a field called **max_time_queued** that is included in the Lookup activity's output stream.  (The Lookup activity is entitled "Most_Recent_Time_Queued" which is referenced in the next step.

The Copy Data activity is next in the run --

```
    @concat('select * from FastQ_Branch_Appointment_Time_At_Time_Customer_Queued where time_queued >= ' , '''', activity('Most_Recent_Time_Queued').output.firstRow.max_time_queued, '''')
```

Select the source data table in the Source section of the Copy activity, then select the Query option underneath it, then put the select query code (shown above) in the Query box.  What this is doing -- it is creating a string that concatenates a) your request for data with the beginning of the Where clause; b) adds a single quote; c) adds the max_time_queued string coming from the Lookup activity; d) then adds a final single quote.  That is, it builds a complete select string that is evaluated at runtime for pulling records.  It runs the Select you've just assembled.

This was a bugger to work out the minutiae for, and I only found this thread when I created my own and was recommended here.  (Wish it had recommended it before I typed my entire thread up, but you know how that goes . . . it's done, and it was a bugger, but it's behind me now and I have a perfect example for the next few hundred times I need to do this very common piece of functionality.)

Note -- **run with in Upsert mode or it will error out** since it pulls a duplicate record (the final record it pulled last time.)  Pulling that final record guarantees you don't lose a record due to roundoff error on the timestamp value.