# Azure Data Factory -- I want to select records from the source based on subselect from the destination

Tags: azure-data-factory, copy-data

I would like to select records to copy (using the Copy Data activity) based on a subselect in the following form --

select from source_table
where timestamp > (select max(timestamp) from destination_table)

This seems like about as elementary a piece of code as one could ask for, but I keep getting an error when I try to figure out how to approach the problem.  It indicates it can't see the destination table when I put that select into the source tab.  I get a similar issue when I put a pre-copy script in the sink.  I have both source and destination tables linked in Azure.

I'm very new to this.  Can someone tell me how to do this?

I'm having a devil of a time writing a google search to ask this question, and in the results to date Microsoft wants me to use a separate table to maintain the most recent loaded timestamp prior to the run, like one would do in FoxPro back in the 90s.  This is a big honkin' table, and I only want to update the last two minutes' worth of additions.  I'm just looking to say "update new stuff since the last update".

My best guess at what should work --

select * from FastQ_Branch_Appointment_Time_At_Time_Customer_Queued
where time_queued > (select max(time_queued) from azure_FastQ_Branch_Appointment_Time_At_Time_Customer_Queued)

I'll mention that both source and destination tables have the same names, but the link to each is different.  Both are linked data sources, one local in SQL*Server the other an Azure SQL table.  Both are tested and work in the Copy Data activity when I'm not doing this select thing.

Comment: Solution appears to be here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69828480/im-using-lookups-in-azure-data-factory-to-update-only-new-data-but-im-getting/76640896#76640896 . . . which was recommended to me when I published this question.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you can take the lookup activity in ADF to retrieve the maximum value of a column named `time_queued` from a table named `azure_FastQ_Branch_Appointment_Time_At_Time_Customer_Queued` of the destination dataset.

[image]

**Query in Lookup activity dataset:**

```sql
select max(time_queued) as max_timestamp from azure_FastQ_Branch_Appointment_Time_At_Time_Customer_Queued
```

- Then take the copy activity and in source dataset give the source query as,

```sql
select * from FastQ_Branch_Appointment_Time_At_Time_Customer_Queued where time_queued > '@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.max_timestamp}'
```

This SQL query selects all rows from the table where the `time_queued` value is greater than the maximum value retrieved by the Lookup activity.

[image]